# How store value of sql server column whose datatype is bit and stored in bool variable

Tags: javascript, css, html, model-view-controller

I'm trying to stored bit value into bool variable by using datatable but it generate an exception. I am using following code

```
if (((bool)dt.Rows[0]["OwnHouse"] == false))
{
    dm.Ownhouse = false;
}
if(((bool)dt.Rows[0]["OwnHouse"] == true)) {
    dm.Ownhouse = true;
}
```

Comment: Try to check for dbnull and also make sure that the column really exist in the datatable

Comment: yes column is exist in the database,but ok now i check db null